Angular Material 3 Custom Theme Not Working (Nx monorepo)
I've got this Angular app within an Nx repo.
After npx nx run testapp:serve
I'm getting the following error:
./src/app/shared/design/testapp.scss - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Undefined function.
   ╷
38 │ $testapp-primary: mat.define-palette($palette-testapp-blue);
   │                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
  src\app\shared\design\testapp.scss 38:16  root stylesheet

./src/app/shared/design/testapp.scss?ngGlobalStyle - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
HookWebpackError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Undefined function.
   ╷
38 │ $testapp-primary: mat.define-palette($palette-testapp-blue);
   │                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
  src\app\shared\design\testapp.scss 38:16  root stylesheet


testapp.scss:
@use "@angular/material" as mat;

@include mat.core();

$palette-testapp-blue: (
  A100: #8897ba,
  A200: #5a698a,
  A400: #2e3f5d,
  contrast: (
    A100: rgb(96, 96, 96),
    A200: rgb(96, 96, 96),
    A400: rgb(96, 96, 96),
  ),
);

$palette-testapp-gold: (
  A100: #ffe5af,
  A200: #cfb37f,
  A400: #9d8452,
  contrast: (
    A100: rgb(96, 96, 96),
    A200: rgb(96, 96, 96),
    A400: rgb(96, 96, 96),
  ),
);

$palette-testapp-red: (
  A100: #ffafae,
  A200: #cf7f7f,
  A400: #9c5153,
  contrast: (
    A100: rgb(96, 96, 96),
    A200: rgb(96, 96, 96),
    A400: rgb(96, 96, 96),
  ),
);

$testapp-primary: mat.define-palette($palette-testapp-blue);
$testapp-accent: mat.define-palette($palette-testapp-gold);
$testapp-warn: mat.define-palette($palette-testapp-red);

$testapp-theme: mat.define-light-theme($testapp-primary, $testapp-accent, $testapp-warn);

@include mat.all-component-themes($testapp-theme);


project.json:
...
"styles": [
    "src/styles.scss",
    "src/app/shared/design/testapp.scss"
],
...


package.json:
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~18.1.2",
    "@angular/cdk": "^18.1.2",
    "@angular/common": "~18.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "~18.1.2",
    "@angular/core": "~18.1.2",
    "@angular/fire": "^18.0.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~18.1.2",
    "@angular/material": "^18.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~18.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~18.1.2",
    "@angular/router": "~18.1.2",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
        "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.14.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~18.1.2",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "~18.1.2",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "~18.1.2",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "~18.1.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "~18.1.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "~18.1.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~18.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~18.1.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "~18.1.2",
    "@nx/angular": "19.5.3",
    "@nx/workspace": "19.5.3",
    "@schematics/angular": "~18.1.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "~5.1.4",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "20.10.3",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~5.1.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~7.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^2.1.0",
    "nx": "19.5.3",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~10.9.2",
    "tslint": "~6.1.3",
    "typescript": "5.5.4"
}


They changed this when using material 3 with angular material 18.
To continue using your old theme you need to use the m2- functions:
$testapp-primary: mat.m2-define-palette($palette-testapp-blue);
$testapp-theme: mat.m2-define-light-theme((color: (primary: $testapp-primary,
                accent: $testapp-accent,
                warn: $testapp-warn,
            ),
            typography: $custom-typography,
            density: 0,
        ));

For the latest theme there are a couple different ways to do it, but one way is:
$my-app-theme-md3: mat.define-theme((color: (
        theme-type: light, 
        use-system-variables: true
    ),
    typography: (
        use-system-variables: true
    ),
    density: (
        scale: 0
    ),
));

https://material.angular.io/guide/theming
Build a custom theme using system variables
https://themes.angular-material.dev/

With Angular v18 and M3 themes the mixins & functions changed quite a lot. mat.define-palette and mat.define-light-theme are both not defined anymore, this is why you are seeing errors in your build. To generate a new M3 theme with custom colors, you can use the ng generate @angular/material:m3-theme schematics. For more information how M3 theming works, see the theming guide.

This is how it work to me:
First, run the schematic: ng generate @angular/material:m3-theme
Second, add this to your main scss file:
@use '@angular/material' as mat;
@use './m3-theme';

@include mat.core();

:root {
  @include mat.all-component-themes(m3-theme.$light-theme);
}
//...

Done, take me a lot of hours to find this.
